# SqlConnection runtime failure after addin System.Data.SqlClient Reference

Tags: c#, runtime-error, .net-core, sqlconnection

I am using .Net Core 2.0.0 and in a project I am using `SqlConnection` class from `System.Data.SqlClient` to establish an SQL Server connection. Up until now there were no problem and I was using it along with `Dapper`. Then I needed to use structured type and long story short I ended up adding `System.Data.SqlClient` package from nuget to build the project. But Then when I run the project, I receive this run-time exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource,
>   Version=4.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Which is strange to me because I have this package installed and it was working just fine before I added `System.Data.SqlClient`. What can cause the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, the problem was I was using .net core 2.0.0 preview2 version. After upgrading to .net core 2.0.0 release version the problem has been solved.